# PHP Illegal string offset when trying to access array values

Tags: php, html, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I might be punching slightly above my weight here or maybe its a really simple problem with a simple solution.

**MY PROBLEM**

1. I cant access array key values in foreach()
2. When creating the array in a function it seems that the array is duplicating, does a double iteration when created(as you can see in image below)

[image]

**STEP 1: Array Creation**

```
     $results = $stmnt->fetchAll();
            if ($stmnt->rowCount() > 0) {
                $totalCorrectPicks = 0;
//--->HERE ARRAY KEYS ARE CREATED FROM QUERYING DB
                foreach ($results as $index => $result) {
                    $returnResult = array('picked' => $result['team'], 'homeScore' => $result['homeScore'], 'awayScore' => $result['awayScore'], 'homeTeam' => $result['homeTeam'],
                        'awayTeam' => $result['awayTeam'], 'score' => $result['score']);
                }//end foreach
//------> HERE ELEMENTS GETS APPENDED TO ARRAY
                    $pickedTeam = $result['team'];
                    if ($result['homeScore'] > $result['awayScore']) {
                        $matchOutcome = $result['homeTeam'];
                        $matchScore = $result['homeScore'];
                        $returnResults['matchOutcome'] = $matchOutcome;
                        $returnResults['matchScore'] = $matchScore;
                    }
                    if ($result['awayScore'] > $result['homeScore']) {
                        $matchOutcome = $result['awayTeam'];
                        $matchScore = $result['awayScore'];
                        $returnResults['matchOutcome'] = $matchOutcome;
                        $returnResults['matchScore'] = $matchScore;
                    }
                    if ($pickedTeam === $matchOutcome) {
                        $totalCorrectPicks++;
                        $margin = abs($matchScore - $result['points']);
                        //INDEX WILL START AT 0 SO WE ADD ONE TO $INDEX
                        $nrGames = $index + 1;
                        $returnResults['totatlCorrectPicks'] = $totalCorrectPicks;
                        $returnResults['margin'] = $margin;
                        $returnResults['nrGames'] = $nrGames;
                    }
                    elseif ($pickedTeam !== $matchOutcome) {
                        $margin = 'wrongPick';
                        $returnResults['margin'] = $margin;
                }
            }
        }
        if(isset($returnResults)){
            print_r($returnResults);
            return $returnResults;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**STEP 2 Calling function and using array; leads to illegal string offset**

```
 <?php $picks = checkUserPicks('5');
        foreach ($picks as $index => $pick){
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td>
            <?php echo $pick['picked']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
             <?php echo $pick['matchOutcome']; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php echo $pick['margin']; ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

NOTE: you can see the array value in the image posted above.

**Questions**

1) Why does it seem like the array is duplicated (see image)?

2) How can I fix the illegal string offset and what causes it?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

New Array Structure after removing `[]` from `$returnResults[]`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After end of `foreach` loop, `matchOutcome, matchScore`, etc are appended to the array. Shouldn't it be inside the loop?

If you are expecting more than one row, then you need to create array by maintaining its index as follows:

```
$returnResults = array(); // Initialize array
foreach ($results as $index => $result) {
    $returnResults[$index] = array('picked' => $result['team'], 'homeScore' => $result['homeScore'],
    'awayScore' => $result['awayScore'], 'homeTeam' => $result['homeTeam'],
    'awayTeam' => $result['awayTeam'], 'score' => $result['score']);

    //------> HERE ELEMENTS GETS APPENDED TO ARRAY
    $pickedTeam = $result['team'];
    if ($result['homeScore'] > $result['awayScore']) {
        $matchOutcome = $result['homeTeam'];
        $matchScore = $result['homeScore'];
        $returnResults[$index]['matchOutcome'] = $matchOutcome;
        $returnResults[$index]['matchScore'] = $matchScore;
    }
    .
    .
    elseif ($pickedTeam !== $matchOutcome) {
        $margin = 'wrongPick';
        $returnResults[$index]['margin'] = $margin;
    }
}//end foreach
```

Comment: Thanks Samir Ill have a quick check and let you know

Comment: No unfortunately it did not solve the problem still illegal string offset and duplicate array problem, *however the array structure has changed*, have a look at updated question.

Comment: do you expect multiple rows to be returned from query?

Comment: I do expect multiple rows yes.

Comment: ok. Understood the problem now. Check my updated answer. Also it seems you have printed array twice in your code due to which it's visible twice.

Comment: Well done sir. You solved the illegal string offset error!!! Thank you! However the bloody array still duplicates (see last image in question update)

Comment: Comment `print_r($returnResults);` and check if you have printed this array anywhere in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163998/discussion-between-samir-and-timothy-coetzee).

Comment: Ok thanks buddy (stupid question how do I get on room just php room or do you create private room)

Comment: Please send me a link if you can! Thanks mate

Comment: Go to https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163998/discussion-between-samir-and-timothy-coetzee